# Parse Codable classes and avoid repetition

Tags: swift, codable

I have a JSON response as the following:

```
{
  "http_status": 200,
  "success": true,
  "has_error": false,
  "error": [
    ""
  ],
  "response": {
    "token": "",
    "verified": false,
    "message": ""
  }
}
```

As far as i can say for an app API usage http_status, success, has_error, error are shared between all APIS and thus i will create a Codable class to handle it, but the response could be different model, so here is what I'm trying to do.

I have created a general response class as the below, so this class i can use for all apis in the project to avoid duplication of same class but different names:

```
class GeneralResponse:Codable {

    let http_status: Int?
    let success, has_error: Bool?
    let error: [String]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case http_status = "http_status"
        case success = "success"
        case has_error = "has_error"
        case error = "error"
    }

    init(http_status: Int?, success: Bool?, has_error: Bool?,error: [String]?) {
        self.http_status = http_status
        self.success = success
        self.has_error = has_error
        self.error = error
    }

}
```

Now i have created the response class which will handle for now the registration response:

```
class RegistrationResponseDetails: Codable {
    let token: String?
    let verified: Bool?
    let message: String?

    init(token: String?, verified: Bool?, message: String?) {
        self.token = token
        self.verified = verified
        self.message = message
    }
}
```

And lets say i need to parse the registration the response so here is what i did, i have created a class and used both of them:

```
class RegistrationResponse: Codable {

    let generalResponse:GeneralResponse?
    let response: RegistrationResponseDetails?

    init(generalResponse: GeneralResponse?, response: RegistrationResponseDetails?) {
        self.generalResponse = generalResponse
        self.response = response
    }
}
```

So i will mainly use RegistrationResponse to parse the response which will parse "generalResponse" which includes http_status, success, has_error, error, and then response will parse the desired response object.

But at some point generalResponse object is always nil and response has the data parsed correctly, what should i do to make generalResponse get parsed without duplication in each api, because in each api i will have generalResponse object so is it possible to solve it ?

**Note:** I'm using Alamofire as the networking library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `GeneralResponse` generic and tell it what type to use when parsing the response:

```
class GeneralResponse<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let http_status: Int?
    let success, has_error: Bool?
    let error: [String]?
    let response: T?
}

class RegistrationResponseDetails: Codable {
    let token: String?
    let verified: Bool?
    let message: String?
}
```

Then you can give it the inner response class when you parse the json:

```
let generalResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(GeneralResponse<RegistrationResponseDetails>.self, from: jsonData)
// generalResponse.response is of type RegistrationResponseDetails?
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simple case

```
class Main:Decodable { 
    let name:String?   // insert all shared vars 
} 

class Sub:Main { 
   let id:String? 
}
```

This will parse

```
{
     "name" : "rr" , 
     "id" : "oo"  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all if

> http_status, success, has_error, error are shared between all APIS

why are the class properties optional?

---

If the mentioned keys are the same but the value for key `response` is different use generics.

In most cases `struct`s are sufficient.

```
struct JSONParser<T : Decodable> {

    struct Response<U : Decodable> : Decodable {
        let httpStatus: Int
        let success, hasError: Bool
        let error: [String]
        let response : U
    }

    let responseData : Response<T>

    init(data: Data) throws {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        responseData = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

Then create the different structs e.g.

```
struct RegistrationResponseDetails : Decodable {
    let token: String
    let verified: Bool
    let message: String
}
```

and parse it

```
let parser = try JSONParser<RegistrationResponseDetails>(data: data)
let registrationResponseDetails = parser.responseData.response
```