# how to use inheritance in decodable model

Tags: swift, decodable

I have some json results that I'm receiving from server. They all have a shared section. and after that in a `results` property, returning values differ.

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": "Ok"
    "data": 
        {
            "count": 3,
            "total": 7,
            "results": [
                {
                    "id": 43424,
                    "title": "some title"
                }
            ]

        }
}
```

as I said, the structure is same for all my models. they only differ in `results`. What I want to do is to avoid writing redundant code, and use inheritance to create a `BaseClass` that has all shared section and my models inherit this `BaseClass`. I've seen some tutorials and posts about Inheritance in `Decodable` models, but still I'm hazy about how can I implement it.

Comment: I would use a generic wrapper instead of inheritance.  For something similar, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53875382/parse-codable-classes-and-avoid-repetition

Comment: Explain how the results part can differ and what you want to achieve

Comment: @dan In this case, I prefer to stick to inheritance

Comment: @JoakimDanielson let's say we have A model with `id` and `title` in `results`. B model has `type` and `item` in `results`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than inheritance and *classes* use generics and *structs* because `Decodable` doesn't support inheritance by default.

For example create a struct `JSONParser`

```
struct JSONParser<T : Decodable> {

    struct ResponseData<U : Decodable> : Decodable {
        let total, count : Int
        let results : [U]
    }

    let code : Int
    let status : String
    let data : ResponseData<T>

    init(data: Data) throws {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        data = try decoder.decode(ResponseData.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

And use it for the dictionary containing `id` and `title`

```
struct Item {
    let id : Int
    let title : String 
}

do {
    let jsonParser = try JSONParser<Item>(data: data)
    let results = jsonParser.data.results
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: This way, I have to use JSONParser<Item> in every time I want whole object(code, status, total,count).

Comment: You get the whole object, only the type of `results` (the generic type of JSONParser) is different.

Comment: I get it, but If I want to create an Instance of it, I have to declare it like this: `let myModel: JSONParser<Item>` and it looks a little not straight way. BTW, It's an elegant way.

Comment: It's just an example. You can rename the outer object `JSONParser` with something else for example `Base` and remove the `init` method. Then decode `Base.self` and you get an object `Base<Item>`